# Query based on a boolean value inside a document field set as Object

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

SO I have a collection set at this :

> rootCollection -> document1 -> "field" : {"flag":true, "name" : "test1"}
>
> rootCollection -> document2 -> "field" : {"flag":false, "name" : "test2"}
>
> rootCollection -> document3 -> "field" : {"flag":true, "name" : "test3"}

So my document contains a field "field1" which is an object.

I would like to make a query to fetch the valid documents where my "flag" is set as true.

Hence returning in this example, only document 1 and 3

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Show us what you have done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
documents := client.Collection("collection_name")

documents_that_are_true = documents.Where("field.flag", "==", true)
```

Answer (score 1):

That should be fairly simple:

```
query := client.Collection("rootCollection").Where("field.flag", "==", true)
```

Comment: Thx as well. Simplistic way.